# Json string to apex class covert and insert record in SFDC

Tags: apex, json, apexrest

i have written below code for post method , an trying to insert response in salesforce, but i am enable to create response in proper format, could you help me why is the issue in below code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Wrp/WrapCaseManager/*')
global with sharing class WrapCaseManager {

    @HttpPost

    global static WrapCaseManager.Caseinsert doPost(WrapCaseManager.Caseinsert  ACCREQ) {

        account acc=(account)ACCREQ.Ac;
        return ACCREQ;
    /*

    }


    global class outerinsert
    {
        public Caseinsert  cin;
    }
    global class Caseinsert {


        public Account Ac;


    }
}
```

below is response :

```
{
    "Ac" : 
    {
        "AccountNumber" : "12345",
        "BillingCity" : "Billing City",
        "BillingPostalCode" : "123456",
        "BillingState" : "Billing State/Provinc",
        "BillingStreet" : "street",
        "Industry" : "Agriculture",
        "Name" : "sample"
    }
}
```

----- issue in valid AccountNumber, can any one help me to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The standard field `Account.AccountNumber` is a text field and you are using the default serialization of `Account` so the JSON will be of this form:

```
"AccountNumber" : "12345"
```

You don't explain where the error is coming from, but ideally you should fix that code to so it doesn't consider a string rather than number invalid (and generally supports whatever you return).

If you really need to force `Account.AccountNumber` to be a number (and have rules that ensures it is), you can create your own object to represent `Account` with the right field type:

```
global class Caseinsert {
    public CustomAccount Ac;
}

global class CustomAccount {
    public Integer AccountNumber;
    public String BillingCity;
    ...
}
```

but will also have to add code to copy the `Account` fields into that object.

Comment: [ { "message" : "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: Ac at [line:3, column:6]", "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR" } ]
 i got the above error .. can you please help, i could like to insert that response in salesforce . so that i can go for my furhter requrements .

Comment: @Vijay Please post the code that produces this error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess issue with AccountNumber value. AccountNumber is number field so you need to pass number not string value

```
{
    "Ac" : 
    {
        "AccountNumber" : 12345, <!--This value-->
        "BillingCity" : "Billing City",
        "BillingPostalCode" : "123456",
        "BillingState" : "Billing State/Provinc",
        "BillingStreet" : "street",
        "Industry" : "Agriculture",
        "Name" : "sample"
    }
}
```